# Pass dictionary to jinja2 template from task loop

Tags: ansible

I pass dictionary from play to task. I use loop to call another task from separate yml file again passing the dictionary. From there I call Jinja2 template and pass the dictionary again. I cannot access the dictionary values from Jinja2.

I tried to pass the dictionary to template with_items and with_dict. Still the same problem.

play:

```
- role: example
      vars:
        brands:
          brand_1:
            name: "brand1"

          brand_2:
            name: "brand2"

          brand_3:
            name: "brand_3"
```

task in role with loop:

```
    - name: Loop through configuration files
      include_tasks: generate_config_files.yml
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', brands) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: outer_item
```

generate_config_files.yml

```
    - name: Generate the configuration files
      template:
        src: "consumer.properties.j2"
        dest: "{{ kafka_location }}/{{ item.key }}/consumer.properties"
        owner: "{{ kafka_user }}"
        group: "{{ kafka_group }}"
        mode: 0644
      with_dict: "{{ outer_item }}"
```

consumer.properties.j2

```
{% for item in outer_item %}
    Name: "{{ item.name }}"
{% endfor %}
```

I expect to access the dictionary value in template and generate the same file with different values based on number of brands in dictionary. So if there are 3 brands I expect to generate 3 files with different Name: inside.

Unfortunately I am getting:

```
"msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'str object' has no attribute 'name'"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Indentation of `vars:` is wrong.

2) The single loop does the job.

3) Iteration in the template is not necessary.

4) Numeric *mode* must be quoted `mode: '0644'`.

The playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role: example
      vars:
        kafka_user: admin
        kafka_group: admin
        kafka_location: /scratch
        brands:
          brand_1:
            name: "brand1"
          brand_2:
            name: "brand2"
          brand_3:
            name: "brand_3"
```

with tasks

```
$ cat roles/example/tasks/main.yml
- include_tasks: generate_config_files.yml
```

, with the included task

```
$ cat roles/example/tasks/generate_config_files.yml 
- name: Generate the configuration files
  template:
    src: "consumer.properties.j2"
    dest: "{{ kafka_location }}/{{ item.key }}/consumer.properties"
    owner: "{{ kafka_user }}"
    group: "{{ kafka_group }}"
    mode: '0644'
  loop: "{{ brands|dict2items }}"
```

, and with the template

```
$ cat roles/example/templates/consumer.properties.j2 
Name: "{{ item.value.name }}"
```

gives

```
$ tree /scratch/brand_*
/scratch/brand_1
└── consumer.properties
/scratch/brand_2
└── consumer.properties
/scratch/brand_3
└── consumer.properties

$ cat /scratch/brand_*/consumer.properties
Name: "brand1"
Name: "brand2"
Name: "brand_3"
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. Works like a charm. I just changed ```loop: "{{ brands|dict2items }}"``` and ```Name: "{{ item.value.name }}"```